# to send response in other function in laravel

Tags: laravel, function, api, video, upload

I have one API for uploading video and this gives the JSON response

```
success": {
    "uid": "****************",
    "original_name": "**********.mp4",
    "duration": "****"
}
```

And I want another API to update videos other data after getting this response.I am not getting how to proceed for this.

```php
function upload(Request $request)
{
    $videofile = $request->file('video');
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'video' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:video/mp4,video/mpeg,video/x-matroska,mp4,mov,ogg,video/3gpp,video/3gpp2,video/x-flv,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv,application/octet-stream,video/x-ms-asf,image/x-tga'],
    ]);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(array('error' > true, 'msg' => 'Please choose the video to upload'));
    } else {

        if ($videofile) {

            $filename = md5_file($videofile->getRealPath());
            $extension = $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $videoId = $filename . time();
            $uniqueFilename = $videoId . '.' . $extension;
            $path = public_path() . '/videos/';


            if ($videofile->move($path, $uniqueFilename)) {
                // get video duration
                $getID3 = new \getID3;
                $videoToUpload = $request->file('video');
                $videoPath = public_path() . '/videos/' . $uniqueFilename;
                $file = $getID3->analyze($videoPath);

                $playtime_seconds = $file['playtime_seconds'];
                $videoDuration = gmdate("H:i:s", $playtime_seconds);
                $myVideoHour = gmdate('H', strtotime($videoDuration));
                if ($myVideoHour == 00) {
                    $myVideoDuration = gmdate('i:s', strtotime($videoDuration));
                } else {
                    $myVideoDuration = $videoDuration;
                }

                $output = array(
                    'uid' => $videoId,
                    'original_name' => $uniqueFilename,
                    'duration' => $videoDuration
                );


                return response()->json(['success' => $output], $this->successStatus);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how do I pass this output in another function for upldating other data of video.

my other function is---

```php
function uploadData(Output $output)
{

    if ($output) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'keywords' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'channel_id' => ['required', 'not_in:0'],
            'description' => ['max:2000'],
            'visibility' => ['required', 'in:public,unlisted,private'],
            'thumbnail' => ['image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif', 'max:6144', 'nullable'],
            'uid' => ['max:2000'],
            'original_name' => ['max:2000'],
            'duration' => ['max:2000'],
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
        }

        $video = new Video;
        $user = Auth::user();
// print_r($user);
// exit;
        $user_id = $user->id;
// $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $Channels = Channel::Where('channels.user_id', $user_id)->get();
        $video->user_id = $user_id;
        $video->uid = $videoId;
        $video->title = $request->title;
        $video->original_name = $uniqueFilename;
        $video->keywords = $request->keywords;
        $video->thumbnail_url = $request->thumbnail_url;
        $video->description = $request->description;
        $video->visibility = $request->visibility;
        $video->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $video->channel_id = $request->channel_id;
        $video->duration = $videoDuration;
        $video->allow_votes = $request->has('allow_votes');
        $video->allow_comments = $request->has('allow_comments');

        if (!empty($request->get('playlistid'))) {
            $video->playlist_id = $request->get('playlistid');
        } elseif (!empty($request->playlist_id)) {
            $video->playlist_id = $request->playlist_id;
        }

        $filename = '';
        $site_url = url('/');
        if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
            $image = $request->file('thumbnail');

            $filename = $video->id . '_' . time() . '_' . uniqid(rand()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(720, 404);
//$img->save($filename);

            $path = 'images/thumbnails/';

            $img->save("$path$filename");

            $url = $site_url . '/' . $path;

            $thumbnails = $url . $filename;
            $video->thumbnail_url = $thumbnails;
        }

        $videoUrl = url('/videos/' . $request->uid);
        $video->save();

        return response()->json([
            "message" => "video record created"
        ], 201);

    }
}
```

It shows that Output is unknown.

Comment: What do you want to update in other api? How you want to do it? THese are important questions which can lead to solution. If you want just update video data from other api you can pass `uid` which is on your response from client on body, or you can put it on url (form using route model binding). Really it depends and i think you should provide more data.

Comment: just create a function in the same class where you write your upload function, on success response of update function call that function using $this->functionName($previousResponse);

Comment: How will you be calling this endpoint from another API? Is the other API on a different server?

Comment: I have updated my question..please check and let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion on how the request/response cycle works. Once Laravel creates a response the only reasonable recipient of that response is the client. It does not make much sense for anyone else to receive the response. What I suggest is to extract your business logic out of the controllers and into a helper class that will help you process your file. Create a new class file e.g. in your `app` folder:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile;

class VideoProcessing
{
    public function processFile(UploadedFile $videofile)
    {
        $filename = md5_file($videofile->getRealPath());
        $extension = $videofile->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $videoId = $filename . time();
        $uniqueFilename = $videoId . '.' . $extension;
        $path = public_path() . '/videos/';


        if ($videofile->move($path, $uniqueFilename)) {
// get video duration
            $getID3 = new \getID3;
            $videoPath = public_path() . '/videos/' . $uniqueFilename;
            $file = $getID3->analyze($videoPath);

            $playtime_seconds = $file['playtime_seconds'];
            $videoDuration = gmdate("H:i:s", $playtime_seconds);
            $myVideoHour = gmdate('H', strtotime($videoDuration));
            if ($myVideoHour == 00) {
                $myVideoDuration = gmdate('i:s', strtotime($videoDuration));
            } else {
                $myVideoDuration = $videoDuration;
            }

            $output = array(
                'uid' => $videoId,
                'original_name' => $uniqueFilename,
                'duration' => $videoDuration
            );
            return $output;

        }
    }

    public function updateFileData(Request $request, array $output)
    {
        $video = new Video;
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $Channels = Channel::Where('channels.user_id', $user_id)->get();
        $video->user_id = $user_id;
        $video->uid = $videoId;
        $video->title = $request->title;
        $video->original_name = $uniqueFilename;
        $video->keywords = $request->keywords;
        $video->thumbnail_url = $request->thumbnail_url;
        $video->description = $request->description;
        $video->visibility = $request->visibility;
        $video->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $video->channel_id = $request->channel_id;
        $video->duration = $videoDuration;
        $video->allow_votes = $request->has('allow_votes');
        $video->allow_comments = $request->has('allow_comments');

        if (!empty($request->get('playlistid'))) {
            $video->playlist_id = $request->get('playlistid');
        } elseif (!empty($request->playlist_id)) {
            $video->playlist_id = $request->playlist_id;
        }

        $filename = '';
        $site_url = url('/');
        if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
            $image = $request->file('thumbnail');

            $filename = $video->id . '_' . time() . '_' . uniqid(rand()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(720, 404);
//$img->save($filename);

            $path = 'images/thumbnails/';

            $img->save("$path$filename");

            $url = $site_url . '/' . $path;

            $thumbnails = $url . $filename;
            $video->thumbnail_url = $thumbnails;
        }

        $videoUrl = url('/videos/' . $request->uid);
        $video->save();        
    }
}
```

Then you can use this code from your controller action:

```php
function upload(Request $request, VideoProcessing $processing)
{
    $videofile = $request->file('video');
    $request->validate([
        'video' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:video/mp4,video/mpeg,video/x-matroska,mp4,mov,ogg,video/3gpp,video/3gpp2,video/x-flv,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv,application/octet-stream,video/x-ms-asf,image/x-tga'],
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'keywords' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'channel_id' => ['required', 'not_in:0'],
        'description' => ['max:2000'],
        'visibility' => ['required', 'in:public,unlisted,private'],
        'thumbnail' => ['image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif', 'max:6144', 'nullable'],
        'uid' => ['max:2000'],
        'original_name' => ['max:2000'],
        'duration' => ['max:2000'],
    ]);
    $output = $processing->processFile($videofile);
    abort_unless($output, 500, 'Unable to move file');       
    $processing->updateFileData($request, $output);
    return response()->json(['success' => $output], $this->successStatus);

}
```